# 'declare' in shell function and scope of environment variable

Tags: bash

Consider the follow test snippet (these are the contents of the file 'declare_test'):

```
function do_foobar ()
{
  unset FOOBAR
  declare -- FOOBAR="default"
  FOOBAR="override"

  echo "At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = \"$FOOBAR\""
}
```

Running do_foobar from the command prompt results in:

```
$ source declare_test
$ do_foobar
At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = "override"
$ echo "FOOBAR=\"$FOOBAR\""
FOOBAR=""
```

In other words, inside the function FOOBAR has the expected value, namely "override", but immediately after the function FOOBAR is *unset*.

If we alter the do_foobar and remove the 'declare' line, then the result is:

```
$ do_foobar
At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = "override"
$ echo "FOOBAR=\"$FOOBAR\""
FOOBAR="override"
```

So, now FOOBAR is NOT unset. Note that functionality of the removed declare is to *set* FOOBAR. If instead of removing the declare we remove the line "FOOBAR="override", then the result becomes:

```
$ do_foobar
At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = "default"
$ echo "FOOBAR=\"$FOOBAR\""
FOOBAR=""
```

So, FOOBAR is still unset after the function.

Finally, if you only remove the unset FOOBAR, give FOOBAR some value before calling do_foobar then the result is that FOOBAR is unchanged!
Hence, despite the declare line, the 'unset' *does* have effect after the function, but the declare itself and subsequent other assignments do no longer because of the declare.

This is a problem for me since I want to call a shell function from PROMPT_COMMAND that restores my environment by sourcing a file that was generated by 'declare -p' (exists of a long list of declare commands).
Apparently bash does not allow one to use declare inside a function, while it DOES allow to just set the variable directly.

Isn't this a bug? Is it fixed in a later version of bash? (I have 4.3.48)
Is there a workaround for this problem that doesn't require me to change the file that I want to source (i.e. that file exists of declare commands and I want to keep it that way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`declare` restricts the scope of a variable inside a function, similar to what `local` does. If you want to override the scope, use `-g`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_foobar ()
{
    unset FOOBAR
    declare -g FOOBAR="default"
    FOOBAR="override"

    echo "At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = \"$FOOBAR\""
}
```

.

```
$ source test.sh
$ do_foobar
At end of do_foobar: FOOBAR = "override"
$ echo "$FOOBAR"
override
```

Comment: Wow, thanks man! I was working on a horrible work around :/. I have used the bash man page many times, but the -g option for some reason has consistently escaped my attention :(. Thanks a ton for your help!